# What is the file extension I should use for dd?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup, dd

I recently copied an entire partition (98 gb) to my backup drive and have since formatted the entire drive (corrupted files.) I ran a live version of Ubuntu and when I ran the dd command I specified the entire drive (/dev/...0) as the input file and the output file as /media/drivename/backup .

How do i make these files readable as a directory structure? I need to access them and restoring them onto a drive makes a major waste of time. Currently reading the files on a Windows Server 2016 machine if it matters, and the files where originally from a Windows install.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you created a full disk clone, you should just be able to mount it like any other partition

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. However it would be nice to access them in Windows.

Comment: This would be better suited for a windows forum then